# DB cyclic reference

Tags: database

How to resolve the cyclic reference on this db scheme?

```
org  ---------------->  users
|                       |
v                       v
hardware -- nodes --> ports--> device
```

An organization has hardware components. A hardware has nodes. A node has ports. A port is connected with a device.
An organization has users. A port is monitored by a user.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you mean Circular Reference, but this is one. Read about [Circular references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference#In_computer_programming)

Comment: Yes, I mean how to have no more than one route from one entity to another.

Comment: take a look at: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/circular_reference.aspx allthough this refers to Circular References but it may help you to change the design. By the way why would you want to save in your databse which user monitors which Port? this changes with time isnt it? the example you mentions is too abstract.

Comment: The requirements assume that each port must be assign to specific user, that only that user can read or write data depending his permissions.